# Dynamic soql : unexpected token: <

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I am getting the above error for :

```
for(String objName : objAPINames){
    for(sObject s : Database.Query('Select Id from ' + objName + 'where CreatedDate <= ' + reqDate)){
        recordIds.add((Id)s.Id);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should be like this.

```
Database.Query('Select Id from ' + objName + 'where CreatedDate <=: reqDate')
```